# Problem starting Telegram bot with pyrogram

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, pyrogram

Hi i am receiving an error starting a bot with nothing on it yet

I am using Pyrogram (2.0.97) and Python (3.9.6)

I didn't developed more code for this bot yet, but i want to use this library (pyrogram) and not other library, because of this decorators that has on this library

Here is the simple code

```
from pyrogram import Client, filters
from pyrogram.types import Message
from pyrogram.types import (
    InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, ReplyKeyboardMarkup
)

TELEGRAM_API_ID = "22284blablabla"
TELEGRAM_API_HASH = "186a3759fc29f394bad2700cc29ecblablabla"
TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN = "blablablablabla"

app = Client(
    'SegBot',
    api_id=TELEGRAM_API_ID,
    api_hash=TELEGRAM_API_HASH,
    bot_token=TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN
)

@app.on_message(filters.private)
async def hello(client, message):
    await message.reply("Hello from Pyrogram!")

print('running!!!')
app.run()
```

And the error is:

```
running!!!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Drives compartilhados\SEG FIS\API\TELEGRAM BOT TEST\bot_test.py", line 151, in <module>
    app.run()
  File "C:\Users\roberto.lins\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyrogram\methods\utilities\run.py", line 84, in run
    self.start()
    return loop.run_until_complete(coroutine)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\roberto.lins\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyrogram\methods\utilities\start.py", line 58, in start
    is_authorized = await self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\roberto.lins\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyrogram\methods\auth\connect.py", line 40, in connect
    await self.load_session()
  File "C:\Users\roberto.lins\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyrogram\client.py", line 586, in load_session
    await Auth(
  File "C:\Users\roberto.lins\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyrogram\session\auth.py", line 254, in create
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\roberto.lins\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyrogram\session\auth.py", line 89, in create
    res_pq = await self.invoke(raw.functions.ReqPqMulti(nonce=nonce))
  File "C:\Users\roberto.lins\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyrogram\session\auth.py", line 67, in invoke
    return self.unpack(response)
  File "C:\Users\roberto.lins\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyrogram\session\auth.py", line 60, in unpack
    return TLObject.read(b)
  File "C:\Users\roberto.lins\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyrogram\raw\core\tl_object.py", line 33, in read
    return cast(TLObject, objects[int.from_bytes(b.read(4), "little")]).read(b, *args)
KeyError: 0
```

Any help, please?

Answer (score 0):

1. Upgrade pyrogram version - `pip install -U pyrogram`
2. Delete session file ending with '.session'. In this case it will be `SegBot.session`.
3. Run your code.

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your Pyrogram version it will fix the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).